# Adding item to a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I saw many questions in Stackoverflow but i didn't find what exactly responds to my query.

I need to add an element to my json object:

```
var JSONObject = {
    "shape0": {
        "id": "id0",
        "x1": 0,
        "x2": 0,
        "y1": 0,
        "y2": 0
    },
    "shape1": {
        "id": "id1",
        "x1": 2,
        "x2": 2,
        "y1": 2,
        "y2": 2
    }
};
```

I used this syntax but in vain:

```
var newShape = "shape2";
JSONObject.newShape.id = "id2";
```

NOTE: The first thing, is that a json object?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: this uses arrays not json object, isn't it?

Comment: Java has *nothing* to do with Javascript. Tag removed.

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense.

Comment: This is not a JSON object. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Joe : could you plz give me the right JSON object

Comment: JSON is a string format for serialising JavaScript objects. This is just a JavaScript object.

Comment: @abualbara **There is no such thing as a JSON object**. JSON is an Object Notation, that uses JavaScript syntax. JavaScript Object Notation; JSON.

Comment: @Bracketworks surely JSON object is a string

Comment: @Joe Really? Do we want to confuse OP more? ;)

Comment: @abualbara - you should read some documentation on JSON, I don't think you understand it (and I'm not helping! (although what I am saying is correct))

Comment: yes i have known JSON but it requires a special format of js object, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to build a similar structure as the rest:

```
JSONObject.shape2 = {
    id: 'id2',
    "x1": 4,
    "x2": 4,
    "y1": 4,
    "y2": 8
};
```

Or:

```
var shapeName = 'shape2';
JSONObject[shapeName] = {
    ...
};
```

Btw, these are *not* JSON objects; they are just objects, in JavaScript.

**Update**

The following wouldn't work:

```
var newShape = "shape2";
JSONObject.newShape.id = "id2";
```

First of all, the notation is wrong; you need to use `[newShape]`. But that's not the main reason; it doesn't work because you can't dereference an object that doesn't exist yet.

```
JSONObject[newShape]
```

This will be undefined, so this:

```
JSONObject[newShape].id
```

Will result in an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: i want to make it json object, how?

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Sadly, I don't think it's going to help.

Comment: JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation meaning you are writing plain Javascript. JSON === javascript object

Comment: @Pinoniq Not sure if you're agreeing with me or not; but yeah, JSON is just a notation; it's not plain JavaScript though, because keys must be quoted in JSON.

Comment: @abualbara It's an object, just like what you have.

Comment: @Jack I do aggree yes, and it is actually plain javascript. JSON is a subset of JS. But yeah, you have some limitations concerning keys etc. My comment was a bit short on that part, apologies ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
var newShape="shape2";
JSONObject[newShape].id = "blar";
```

Comment: then, i can use that: JSONObject.shape2.id ?